# Mock a web page for UI Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, mocking, ui-testing, gui-testing

We are using both Angular and Rails applications at our company.  Is there a way to mock a web page to test the UI?  Essentially I want to jump midway into an application, so I don't have to take time logging in, creating our object, tweaking the object, then finally getting to what I can test.

I was looking at something like [MSL](http://finraos.github.io/MSL/), but am unsure if it's really what I need.

Comment: "Mock a web page" as in...what, exactly?  Is this from Rails' point of view or from Angular's point of view?

Comment: This is from a testing point of view. Because rails and angular respond with entire html, it's hard to fake. Is there a way to have a url respond with a preset webpage in the context of the application? For instance, localhost:3000/shows/1 to respond with a set of html that I force with a json object to fill in what's necessary. I don't know if noting rails or angular is important, but included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out MSL is what I wanted.  My application depends on other applications for communication.  In order to isolate my isolation, I can use MSL to mock the responses from and the requests to my dependent applications fairly easily.  In my configuration I switch my external dependency to localhost:8001 (or whatever port msl is running on).

### Edit

I rewrote MSL, specifically for my purposes and made it a little easier.  The server is a node program, and the client is only in ruby as of now.

[mobe-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobe-server)

[mobe-client](https://rubygems.org/gems/mobe-client)